# Do you have to reimport external modules when they have been already imported in an other imported module?

Tags: python, import, module

Say you have two modules `mod1.py` and `mod2.py`.

In `mod1.py` you import an external (to the package you are writing) module, say `numpy` and in `mod2.py` you import `mod1`:

Inside `mod1.py`:

```
import numpy as np
```

Inside `mod2.py`:

```
import mod1
```

Now if a line of code inside `mod2` calls `np` this raises an error:

> NameError: name 'np' is not defined

How can I avoid importing external modules in every module (= file) of my package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import` can do two things:

1. Create a module
2. Define a new variable in the current scope bound to a module

A module `foo` will only be created *once* per process, no matter how many times `import foo` is executed. However, `import foo` will *always* bind the module to the name `foo`, even if `foo` is already bound (to that module or some other value) in the current scope.

`import numpy as np` binds the name `np` to the `numpy` module in the global scope of `mod1`.

`import mod1` only binds the name `mod1`; it does not bring the global variables of `mod1` into the global scope of `mod2`. For that, you would need something like

```
from mod1 import np
```

or just use `mod1.np` in `mod2`.

What you appear to be looking for is a way to put `np` into a process-wide namespace, accessible from any module. Python only has one such namespace, the built-in namespace, but you cannot add names to that. You only have the individual module-global namespaces.

Above, I mentioned that a module is only created once. This is because `import` will first check if the requested module already exists in `sys.modules`. You *could* access `np` from anywhere after it's been imported once with

```
sys.modules['numpy']  # The "real" name, not the import-defined alias
```

However, there's no guarantee that `numpy` *has* been defined yet, and you still have to import `sys` to get access to `sys.modules`, so this doesn't gain you anything over simply using

```
import numpy as np
```

wherever you want `np`.

Comment: _What you appear to be looking for is a way to put np into a process-wide namespace, accessible from any module._  
That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to think about here: *importing* modules, and *naming those imports*.

From your point of view, these problems are the same: if you want something in the namespace, you import it:

```py
# mod1.py
import numpy as np
```

There is no other way to get something into your module's namespace.  (Alright, there's no other way which doesn't involve messing around with `sys.modules` to do exactly the same thing).

But what has python done here?  Firstly, it has looked up `numpy` in `sys.modules`.  If it isn't there, it loads numpy, and inserts the loaded module into `sys.modules["numpy"]`.  Then it binds a local name `np` to point at `sys.modules["numpy"]`.  Thus if you import `mod1` you can access its imports:

```py
#mod2.py
import mod1
mod1.np
```

(Aside: this rigorous enforcing of namespaces is a great boon, and makes python *much* less susceptible to random name collision errors.  It simplifies your job as a coder, since you don't have to worry about names in your imported module overwriting other stuff, so you don't have to resort to things like naming functions `$get` or something else 'very unlikely' to be used).

### Performance

Does this mean that python will load the same module multiple times if you import it multiple times?  No.  Python only ever imports a module once: after that it just binds a local name to point to the module in `sys.modules`.  So the only performance penalty for doing:

```py
#mod2
import numpy as np
import mod1
np
```

Is binding a name, which is trivial (if you care that much, you don't want to use python).  There is no reason to do this:

```py
# mod2.py
from mod1 import np
np
```

unless it is easier not to think about where your functions come from (you will frequently see 'for convenience, you can import `x` from library `y`, e.g. importing components of `Starlette` directly from `FastApi`).

### Being Declarative

Managing namespaces like this has one massive advantage: when I read your code I know *exactly* where `function_xyz()` comes from.  Either you defined it in scope, or you imported it into this scope.  Compare this with e.g. JS or R when I have to ask---where exactly does xyz come from? and then go and look it up.  For the same reason most linters will get cross with you if you write

```py
from numpy import *
```

And insist that you should explicitly import what you need.

Comment: _this rigorous enforcing of namespaces is a great boon, and makes python much less susceptible to random name collision errors. It simplifies your job as a coder,[...] else 'very unlikely' to be used)_ 

If I get correctly: no-one uses this syntax (noob practice) but you seem to recommend it ?

Comment: what I meant was: unlike in other languages, where you *expect* your modules to be stuffed into someone else's namespace, or where there is only a global namespace, you don't have to worry about it unless people do `from yourmodule import *`, which is bad practice anyway.  In languages where this is not a valid assumption, if you expect your code to be used everywhere you have to think quite hard about what you name things.  In python you can bank on people doing `import yourmodule; yourmodule.thing` and not worry about whether they have a `thing` in their namespace.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions for wording the answer more clearly.  I started this answer before the other answer was posted, but we cover substantially the same ground.  I went into a bit more detail to justify keeping this one around.

Comment: Your answer is fine, thank you :).